# Run local code in the Jupyter notebook on remote server via kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to run local code using local data on a remote server and get back execution results back to my Jupyter notebook cells.

Not usual scheme "run Jupyter notebook remotely, connect to remote notebook via ssh tunneling" but more sophisticated via custom remote kernel which I may choose from the kernel list, and run local code on remote server seamlessly.

Some packages (like this -- https://pypi.org/project/remote-kernel) mention that it is possible, but look dated and come with limited usage instructions.

Anyone knows how to implement this? If so, be as more detailed as possible, thanks!